# Regex matching "time" values in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match several patterns in a string with a regular expression add a delimiter and add them to a string or list. Description is the string i'm trying to test.

Here's the text I'm trying to match "01:00 02:00 03:00"
previous attempts I was able to match "01:00", but I want to match all 3 cases.

```
var pattern = @"^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$";
var ReturnTime = "";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(Description, pattern)) {
  ReturnTime += match.Value + ";";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove your anchors `^` and `$` for that purpose:

```
var pattern = @"(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)";
               ^                                                ^
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7C2%5B0-3%5D)%3A)%3F(%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd)%3A)%3F(%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cd)&i=01%3A00%2002%3A00%2003%3A00)

Answer (score 0):

```
(0[0-9]|1[1-2]):[0-5][0-9](?=[^0-9])
```

will match standard time ([Link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(0%5b0-9%5d%7c1%5b1-2%5d)%3a%5b0-5%5d%5b0-9%5d(%3f%3d%5b%5e0-9%5d)&i=01%3a00+05%3a59+00%3a00+12%3a34%0d%0a13%3a34+21%3a00+23%3a59%0d%0a24%3a00+00%3a60+00%3a99+01%3a1+01%3a111)), while

```
([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](?=[^0-9])
```

will match military time ([Link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5B0-1%5D%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-3%5D)%3A%5B0-5%5D%5B0-9%5D(%3F%3D%5B%5E0-9%5D)&i=01%3A00%2005%3A59%2000%3A00%2012%3A34%0D%0A13%3A34%2021%3A00%2023%3A59%0D%0A24%3A00%2000%3A60%2000%3A99%2001%3A1%2001%3A111)).